# Can I use pip to install my own package from PyPI?

Tags: python, pip, pypi

If contributing to The Python Package Index (PyPI) like described on this [page](http://guide.python-distribute.org/creation.html), will it automatically be possible to install the package using pip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you contribute a package to PyPi, it will become available for installation by commands like `pip` or `easy_install`.

PS: If you think of using private pypi, look to [`devpi`](http://doc.devpi.net/latest/) project - seems very good.